# Deserialize Datetime from Custom Settings in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, json, datetime, deserialize

Is there a helper utility for Lightning components to convert values from Datetime objects into a deserialized value? I have two Datetime values in Custom Settings...

```
My_Start_Date__c
My_End_Date__c
```

...and my Lightning component is getting back serialized values:

```
My_Start_Date__c: "2020-06-01T19:17:00.000Z"
My_End_Date__c: "2020-07-01T04:30:00.000Z"
```

Are they any Lightning features that will deserialize this, or is that something that I will need to convert to on my own in order to be able to effectively read the timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Date constructor:

```
let startDate = new Date(record.My_Start_Date__c);
```

From there, you can use other [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) methods for formatting, adjusting, etc.

Note that this is a standard JavaScript feature, which is why there's no need for a "LWC-only" add-on utility.